# aws + centos 7 + built nginx ngx_pagespeed + php-fpm = file not found

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx, centos, mod-pagespeed

I have tried everything and have verified everything is running on the same group.

Also chown'd files to nginx:nginx and chmod'd them to 755
Here is server block

```
server {
listen 80;

root /var/www/example.com/public_html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name example.com;

location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

# Pagespeed main settings

pagespeed on;
pagespeed FileCachePath /var/ngx_pagespeed_cache;

# Ensure requests for pagespeed optimized resources go to the pagespeed
# handler and no extraneous headers get set.

location ~ "\.pagespeed\.([a-z]\.)?[a-z]{2}\.[^.]{10}\.[^.]+" { add_header "" ""; }
location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_static/" { }
location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_beacon" { }

location ~ \.php$ {
try_files $uri =404;

fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
}
}
```

Comment: What's the resource you're trying to access? Just http://example.com ? If so, are you sure that `index.php` exists in `/var/www/example.com/public_html`?

Comment: I have to separate files that I am trying to access, info.php and a test.php.

There is an index.html that returns properly. FYI php works from the terminal.

Comment: Response from nginx error log: 23820#0: *11 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream

Answer (score 0):

Followed this tutorial about SELinux. I am new to CentOS so I was unfamiliar with all of the security parameters.

https://www.cloudinsidr.com/content/troubleshooting-php-7-tcp-sockets-with-selinux-on-centos-7-rhelfedora/